# How to show values on x axis using mpchart library?

Tags: java, android, linechart

I have values like `integer` or `date` value but don't know **where** to use them in Android.

So that when I zoom in the values remain at the same place and between the values there is an empty space.

I want to show the values between them like [1 2 3] on graph only showing values 1,2,3 but not showing like 1,1.1,1.2,1.3 ... 2.8 2.9(when zooming in)?

```
final ArrayList<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    xLabel.add("1");
    xLabel.add("2");
    xLabel.add("3");
    xLabel.add("4");
    xLabel.add("5");
    xLabel.add("6");
XAxis xAxis = line.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return xLabel.get((int)value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: upload your code please for better understanding.

Comment: set xAxis granularity to 1 using => setGranularity(1f);

Comment: But when zooming in the empty space between them increases. I want the values to be changed in fraction form not remain in the whole form.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the granularity and add the interval for it like

```
XAxis xAxis = mBarChart.getAxisLeft();
xAxis.setGranularity(0.1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

In your case the interval is 0.1

Comment: values are repeating on the x-axis. By putting granularity to 0.1f.

Comment: then make it false

Comment: Thanks, it works on this data.
But how to do it on date value like 11-05-2015 13-05-2018.

Comment: for that you might have to use Value Formatter i think, have a look at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface

Answer (score 0):

Set xAxis granularity to 1:

```
private void setXAxisGranularity(Chart chart)
{
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
}
```